# Нагрузочный тест в asp.net

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, нагрузочное-тестирование

Доброго времени суток! Читаю на хабре [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/168869/) про кэширование.
Вижу там такие слова

> Сразу создал нагрузочный тест на одну минуту, который открывает главную страницу. Получилось 60 страниц в секунду (все тесты запускал в дебаге)

Сразу захотелось проверить свои проекты таким же образом. Стал искать, как это сделать, но почему-то ничего не нашел. Не знаю, может плохо гуглил. Подскажите пожалуйста как выполнить такой тест для своего asp.net mvc приложения? заранее спасибо!